# How can I fix a broken CFL softbox part?

Tags: softbox

I recently purchased a cheap eBay softbox, and I have seemed to have broken the very cheaply made small grip head under the light unit. I have opened it up and it looks like the gears grinded together and there is no longer any grip for it to stay still. The problem was, I never tightened it up enough and it just slid and rubbed together and chewed off the rest of the grip head. I have tried to find a replacement part but either they don't make them, or I'm just not saying the proper name for the part. Can anyone help me with either supplying me with a part name, or how to fix it?

BTW. I use these softboxes for video producing.

Here is the link for the softbox on ebay: 
[Ebay Softbox](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Photography-Soft-Box-Studio-Continuous-Video-Lighting-Boom-Light-Arm-Softbox-Kit-/281445182703?hash=item418770acef:g:ItsAAOSw-nZTmpU3)

If you have more questions, or something didn't make any sense that i said, just ask a question. Thanks, image seen below is of the entire unit, look under the logo and that's the part. :)

[image: picture of CFL light unit]

Answer (score 1):

Its called a "star knob" fastener. These are readily available at hardware stores. As to the friction grip it attaches too -- Take the unit to a bicycle repair shop, they will likely have the parts you need. If not, they will point you in the right direction.